# add index fails, too many indexes problem in spring boot with mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, indexing

I am using spring boot project which deals with mongodb.
While creating document via spring boot, in my java class I have a field of object type which further contains other object type field so on.
So the problem is while starting application, it creates indexes with all combinations of Objects.
Then mongo refuses to create too many indexes, is there any way to ignore it or to solve this problem.

Comment: you can use @Transient annotation on top of a field if you want, that object should not be persisted to db. You can use this, if you have a recursion in the links between objects.

Comment: Thanks for your comments) but saving in db is not main problem, the thing is its creating too many indexes for recursive object. May be @Transient will not save data in db but we are concerned with indexes.